# Как сделать слайдер swiper одиночным, чтобы другие слайды не были видны?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
  
    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
  });

  const swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper2', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    
    slidesPerView: 1, // this

  
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next2',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev2',
    },


    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination_2',
      clickable: true,
    },

  });
```

```css
.blog{
    padding-top: 171px;
}

.blog_titles{
    text-align:center;
    color: #3D4F9F;
}

.blog_subtitle_p{
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.blog_title_h3{
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 92px;
}

.blog_card{
    border: 1px solid #D8E3FE;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 50px #EFF4FF;
    /*max-width: 958px;
    margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.blog_card_left_images{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 0fr);
    grid-column-gap: 12.84px;
}

.left_big_img{
    width: 267px;
    height: 267px;
    position: relative;
  
}

.blog_btn{
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 82%;
    left: 90%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.blog_btn img{
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}

.left_small_img{
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 13.74px;
}

.left_small_images{
    width: 126.84px;
    height: 126.58px;
}

.blog_card{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.blog_card_right{
    max-width: 408px;
    margin-top: 92px;
    margin-right: 81px;
}

.blog_right_title_h3{
    color: #3D4F9F;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.blog_right_text_p{
    color: #8D96BD;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 27px;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    margin-bottom: 44px;
}

.blog_right_a1{
    background: #D2E1FF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #3A79FF;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 13px 15px;
}

.blog_right_a2{
    color: #A6B6DA;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 13px 15px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.swiper-pagination_2{
    text-align: center;
    
}

.swiper-button-next2{
    font-size: 50px;
}

.swiper-button-prev2{
    font-size: 50px;
}

.swiper2{
    width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide{
    
}
```

```html
<section class="blog">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="blog_content">
                <div class="blog_titles">
                    <div class="blog_subtitle">
                        <p class="blog_subtitle_p">
                            OUR RESOURCES
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog_title">
                        <h3 class="blog_title_h3">
                            Start reading our blog
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper2">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="blog_card">
                                <div class="blog_card_left">
                                    <div class="blog_card_left_images">
                                        <div class="left_big_img">
                                            <img src="img/blog_left_big.png" alt="">
                                            <button class="blog_btn">
                                                <img src="img/blog_search.png" alt="">
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="left_small_img">
                                            <div class="left_small_images">
                                                <img src="img/blog_right_small_1.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="left_small_images">
                                                <img src="img/blog_right_small_two.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_card_right">
                                    <div class="blog_right_title">
                                        <h3 class="blog_right_title_h3">
                                            How to start planning
                                        </h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="blog_right_text">
                                        <p class="blog_right_text_p">
                                            Quidam vocibus eum ne, erat consectetuer voluptatibus ut nam. Eu usu vidit
                                            tractatos, vero tractatos ius an, in mel diceret persecuti. Natum petentium
                                            principes mei ea. Tota everti periculis vis ei, quas tibique pro at, eos ut
                                            decore ...
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="blog_right_links">
                                        <a href="#" class="blog_right_a1">Read now</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="blog_right_a2">Add to your bookmarks</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="blog_card">
                                <div class="blog_card_left">
                                    <div class="blog_card_left_images">
                                        <div class="left_big_img">
                                            <img src="img/blog_left_big.png" alt="">
                                            <button class="blog_btn">
                                                <img src="img/blog_search.png" alt="">
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="left_small_img">
                                            <div class="left_small_images">
                                                <img src="img/blog_right_small_1.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="left_small_images">
                                                <img src="img/blog_right_small_two.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_card_right">
                                    <div class="blog_right_title">
                                        <h3 class="blog_right_title_h3">
                                            How to start planning
                                        </h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="blog_right_text">
                                        <p class="blog_right_text_p">
                                            Quidam vocibus eum ne, erat consectetuer voluptatibus ut nam. Eu usu vidit
                                            tractatos, vero tractatos ius an, in mel diceret persecuti. Natum petentium
                                            principes mei ea. Tota everti periculis vis ei, quas tibique pro at, eos ut
                                            decore ...
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="blog_right_links">
                                        <a href="#" class="blog_right_a1">Read now</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="blog_right_a2">Add to your bookmarks</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="blog_card">
                                <div class="blog_card_left">
                                    <div class="blog_card_left_images">
                                        <div class="left_big_img">
                                            <img src="img/blog_left_big.png" alt="">
                                            <button class="blog_btn">
                                                <img src="img/blog_search.png" alt="">
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="left_small_img">
                                            <div class="left_small_images">
                                                <img src="img/blog_right_small_1.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="left_small_images">
                                                <img src="img/blog_right_small_two.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_card_right">
                                    <div class="blog_right_title">
                                        <h3 class="blog_right_title_h3">
                                            How to start planning
                                        </h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="blog_right_text">
                                        <p class="blog_right_text_p">
                                            Quidam vocibus eum ne, erat consectetuer voluptatibus ut nam. Eu usu vidit
                                            tractatos, vero tractatos ius an, in mel diceret persecuti. Natum petentium
                                            principes mei ea. Tota everti periculis vis ei, quas tibique pro at, eos ut
                                            decore ...
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="blog_right_links">
                                        <a href="#" class="blog_right_a1">Read now</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="blog_right_a2">Add to your bookmarks</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-pagination_2"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev2">12</div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next2">12</div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

r.com/EANtE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я тут недавно ковырялся с этим слайдером.
Сильно глубоко в настройках не лазил. Просто работал с тем, что досталась.
Там вот такие настройки:

```
new Swiper('.swiper', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    observer: true,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    grid: {
        rows: 3,
        fill: 'row',
    },
    autoHeight: true,

    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

    scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    },

    breakpoints: {
        320: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            grid: {
                rows: 1,
                fill: 'row',
            },
        },
        421: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            grid: {
                rows: 2,
                fill: 'row',
            },
        },
        721: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            grid: {
                rows: 3,
                fill: 'row',
            },
        },
        1024: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            grid: {
                rows: 2,
                fill: 'row',
            },
        },
    }
})
```

slidesPerView - кол-во видимых элементов

```
breakpoints: {
    320: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
```

количество элементов для ширины экрана больше 320

нужно остальное - читайте документацию. )